# What is missing to reproduce CVE-2022-32250?

Tags: network, c, cve, use-after-free

I want to reproduce [CVE-2022-32250](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2022-32250/). I found this [this git repo](https://github.com/theori-io/CVE-2022-32250-exploit) as a repository for the exploit and a code proof of concept provided [here](https://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2022/05/31/1).

So I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on VM, and installed kernel version 5.15.0-27, then installed libmnl-dev / libnfmnl-dev, and tried to run both of the aforementioned codes, but none of them succeeded!

Can you please help me or tell me what is missing?

[image]

Comment: It will be a pretty big job to figure this out. Next step is to edit the exploit to add some debug, to see where it's failing.

Comment: It's not the easiest thing to do when you are beginner, and it's my first cve to investigate, i just wanted a way to ensure that my environment is vulnerable or not :)